# Can you put EFI partition on d: and the BOOT and Data from C: on a new SSD?

Tags: ssd, efi

Can you put EFI partition on d: and the BOOT and Data from C: on a new SSD?. The system is a Tower running Windows 10 Home. The system came with a 256 SSD which has the EFI partition Disk 0 and the Boot information from Disk 1 letter C:.  I would like to combine both into one Samsung 860 EVO 1T drive. What I have read so far is I'm asking for trouble with all types of issues if I try to do this. Is there good software available to accomplish without doing a new load of Windows 10. I also read the speed gain is negligible and not worth the risk of messing it up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The EFI partition isn't typically assigned a drive letter.  In fact by default it's given an attribute to prevent that from happening.  Whey do you want to do that? Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question.  The EFI and system partition typically should be on the same disk,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have just done that by accident in one of my many installations in the last weeks. I had my external SSD plugged in via USB cable, and I installed Linux with EFI base and GPT partitioning. The EFI partition was created at the end of my Windows SSD disk instead of the same SSD, I must have chosen the wrong drive then (which is no drama when you make a fresh start on both disks anyway). And when I took off the Windows SSD that had the Linux EFI partition at the end, Linux could not EFI boot Linux anymore, obviously.

I had to install a new EFI partitition on the Linux SSD to be "independent" in future.

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626189/442338) for details. I used the UEFI hybrid method, but there are also pure EFI methods in that tutorial link to the main EFI guides, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625537/442338).

I would still add the EFI partition to the same drive, e.g. at the end, then the disks are independent. For example, I use an external SSD that I plug in and off using a caddy in the former DVD drive. If you want that flexibility, and you take it off and your Linux cannot start anymore, you will try to keep EFI partition on the drive that needs it. If not for now, then for future flexibility.